# Meteor React Uncaught ReferenceError: Peer is not defined

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I have loaded in the js file for peer js and when I type Peer on my console line in my browser it shows me the object.
However when I load the page I get: 
Chat.jsx:18 Uncaught ReferenceError: Peer is not defined

```
export default class Chat extends React.Component{

constructor(){
 super();   

             // Create a Peer instance
        window.peer = new Peer({  // the error is on this line
        key: 'thisismykey',  // get a free key at http://peerjs.com/peerserver
        debug: 3,
        config: {'iceServers': [
                { url: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' },
                { url: 'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302' },
            ]}
       });
    }
```

When I type Peer into the console I get:

```
  Function Peer(id, options) {
  if (!(this instanceof Peer)) return new Peer(id, options);
  EventEmitter.call(this);
  // Deal with overloading
  if (id && id.constructor == Object) {
  optio… // etc
```

I have tried using componentOnMount but that also gives the same issue.

This is due to the loading of the .js file I am thinking. But I am loading it in the index file the same as all the other .js files which are working right.

```
<script src="assets/js/peer.js"></script>.
```

I know there is a different way to load the files but the others work so I am wondering why this does not.

Is there a way to get the code to run when the component is ready.

When I just add a button to call the  // Create a Peer instance code it works fine and the whole thing works. So the js does get loaded, just at the wrong time I am thinking.

Thanks!

Comment: do you mean componentDidMount?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the window object (window.peer) you should wait for the DOM to render.

From React [Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dom-event-listeners.html):

> componentDidMount is called after the component is mounted and has a DOM representation. This is often a place where you would attach generic DOM events.

---

You may have a good reason for loading scripts in tags. If you don't you may have better luck just including it in your packages ([see guide](https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html)).

```
meteor npm install --save peer
```

then

```
import peer from 'peer';
```

in every component you are using peer

---

Then something like (window.peer removed):

```
export default class Chat extends React.Component{

constructor(){
  super();   
  this.state {
        peer = new Peer({
          key: 'thisismykey',  // get a free key at http://peerjs.com/peerserver
          debug: 3,
          config: {'iceServers': [
            { url: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' },
            { url: 'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302' },
        ]}
    };
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.state.peer.on('open', (id) => {
        console.log('My peer ID is: ' + id);
        this.setState({
            my_id: id,
            initialized: true
        });
    });

    this.state.peer.on('connection', (connection) => {
        console.log('someone connected');
        console.log(connection);

        this.setState({
            conn: connection
        }, () => {
            this.state.conn.on('open', () => {
                this.setState({
                    connected: true
                });
            });

            this.state.conn.on('data', this.onReceiveData);
        });
    });
}

render() {
    var result;
    if(this.state.initialized){
        result = (
            <div>
                <div>
        Your PeerJS ID: <strong className="">{this.state.my_id}</strong>
                </div>
                {this.state.connected ? 'Your Connected' : 'Your Not Connected'}
            </div>
        );
    } else {
        result = <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    return result;
}
```

NOT TESTED